Issue with CompoundShape Scaling in BulletSharp/Assimp Integration
I’m trying to create a CompoundShape using BulletSharp and Assimp for my 3D physics engine. The collider works perfectly when the scaling is uniform across all axes (e.g., 1,1,1 or 2,2,2). However, when I apply non-uniform scaling (e.g., 1,2,1), the collider behaves incorrectly.
Here is the relevant part of my code:
using Assimp;
using BulletSharp;
using Genesis.Core.GameElements;
using Genesis.Math;
using Genesis.Physics;

public class CompoundMeshCollider2 : ColliderBehavior3D
{
    public CompoundMeshCollider2(PhysicHandler physicHandler) : base(physicHandler) { }

    public void CreateCollider(String path, int collisionGroup = -1, int collisionMask = -1)
    {
        var element = (Element3D)this.Parent;
        var compoundShape = new CompoundShape(false);

        var btTranslation = BulletSharp.Math.Matrix.Translation(element.Location.ToBulletVec3());
        var btScale = BulletSharp.Math.Matrix.Scaling(1.0f);
        var btRotation = BulletSharp.Math.Matrix.RotationX(element.Rotation.X) *
                         BulletSharp.Math.Matrix.RotationY(element.Rotation.Y) *
                         BulletSharp.Math.Matrix.RotationZ(element.Rotation.Z);
        var btStartTransform = btTranslation * btRotation * btScale;

        Assimp.AssimpContext importer = new Assimp.AssimpContext();
        var model = importer.ImportFile(path, Assimp.PostProcessPreset.TargetRealTimeQuality | Assimp.PostProcessSteps.Triangulate);

        foreach (var mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            int[] indicies = mesh.GetIndices();
            float[] verticies = mesh.Vertices.SelectMany(v => new float[] { v.X, v.Y, v.Z }).ToArray();
            var meshScale = BulletSharp.Math.Matrix.Scaling(element.Size.ToBulletVec3());
            var node = FindMeshNode(model.RootNode, mesh.Name);
            var transform = GetMatrix(model.RootNode.Transform) * GetMatrix(node.Transform);

            TriangleIndexVertexArray triangle = new TriangleIndexVertexArray(indicies, verticies);
            BvhTriangleMeshShape shape = new BvhTriangleMeshShape(triangle, true);
            shape.LocalScaling = new BulletSharp.Math.Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            compoundShape.AddChildShape(transform, shape);
        }

        compoundShape.LocalScaling = TransformVector(element.Size);
        compoundShape.CalculateLocalInertia(0);

        Collider = new BulletSharp.CollisionObject
        {
            CollisionShape = compoundShape,
            UserObject = this.Parent,
            WorldTransform = btStartTransform
        };
        PhysicHandler.ManageElement(this, collisionGroup, collisionMask);
    }

    private static Node FindMeshNode(Node root, String meshname)
    {
        return root.FindNode(meshname);
    }

    private static BulletSharp.Math.Matrix GetMatrix(Assimp.Matrix4x4 matrix)
    {
        return new BulletSharp.Math.Matrix(
            matrix.A1, matrix.B1, matrix.C1, matrix.D1,
            matrix.A2, matrix.B2, matrix.C2, matrix.D2,
            matrix.A3, matrix.B3, matrix.C3, matrix.D3,
            matrix.A4, matrix.B4, matrix.C4, matrix.D4
        );
    }

    private static BulletSharp.Math.Vector3 TransformVector(Vec3 vec)
    {
        return new BulletSharp.Math.Vector3(vec.X, vec.Y, vec.Z);
    }
}

Observed Issue:
Uniform scaling (1,1,1 or 2,2,2) works correctly.
Non-uniform scaling (1,2,1) causes incorrect behavior.
I suspect that the issue is related to how scaling transformations are applied either to individual meshes or to the CompoundShape. I’ve tried adjusting shape.LocalScaling and compoundShape.LocalScaling, but the results are still incorrect.
What I’m Looking For:

Suggestions for debugging this issue.
Insights into the correct way to handle non-uniform scaling with CompoundShape in BulletSharp.
Any known pitfalls when integrating Assimp and BulletSharp with non-uniform scaling.


This seems to work for me
using Assimp;
using BulletSharp;
using Genesis.Core.GameElements;
using Genesis.Math;
using Genesis.Physics;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Genesis.Core.Behaviors.Physics3D
{
    public class CompoundMeshCollider2 : ColliderBehavior3D
    {
        public CompoundMeshCollider2(PhysicHandler physicHandler) : base(physicHandler)
        {
        }

        public void CreateCollider(String file, int collisionGroup = -1, int collisionMask = -1)
        {
            Element3D element = (Element3D)this.Parent;

            Assimp.AssimpContext importer = new Assimp.AssimpContext();
            var model = importer.ImportFile(file, Assimp.PostProcessPreset.TargetRealTimeQuality | Assimp.PostProcessSteps.PreTransformVertices);
            var compoundShape = new CompoundShape();

            var scale = Utils.GetElementWorldScale(element);
            var btStartTransform = ColliderBehavior3D.GetBtTransform(element);

            foreach (var mesh in model.Meshes)
            {
                int[] indicies = mesh.GetIndices();
                float[] verticies = mesh.Vertices.SelectMany(v => new float[] { v.X, v.Y, v.Z }).ToArray();

                TriangleIndexVertexArray triangle = new TriangleIndexVertexArray(indicies, verticies);
                BvhTriangleMeshShape shape = new BvhTriangleMeshShape(triangle, true);

                compoundShape.AddChildShape(BulletSharp.Math.Matrix.Identity, shape);
            }

            compoundShape.LocalScaling = scale.ToBulletVec3();
            compoundShape.CalculateLocalInertia(0f);

            Collider = new CollisionObject();
            Collider.UserObject = element;
            Collider.CollisionShape = compoundShape;
            Collider.WorldTransform = btStartTransform;
            PhysicHandler.ManageElement(this, collisionGroup, collisionMask);
        }

        public override void CreateCollider(int collisionGroup = -1, int collisionMask = -1)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private static Node FindMeshNode(Node root, String meshname)
        {
            return root.FindNode(meshname);
        }

        private static BulletSharp.Math.Matrix GetMatrix(Assimp.Matrix4x4 matrix)
        {
            return new BulletSharp.Math.Matrix(
                matrix.A1, matrix.B1, matrix.C1, matrix.D1, // Erste Spalte
                matrix.A2, matrix.B2, matrix.C2, matrix.D2, // Zweite Spalte
                matrix.A3, matrix.B3, matrix.C3, matrix.D3, // Dritte Spalte
                matrix.A4, matrix.B4, matrix.C4, matrix.D4  // Vierte Spalte
            );
        }

        private static BulletSharp.Math.Vector3 TransformVector(Vec3 vec)
        {
            return new BulletSharp.Math.Vector3(vec.X, vec.Y, vec.Z);
        }
    }
}

The class to calculate the transform matrix from the ColliderBehavior3D class
public static BulletSharp.Math.Matrix GetBtTransform(GameElement element)
{
    var location = Utils.GetElementWorldLocation(element);
    var rotation = Utils.GetElementWorldRotation(element);
    var scale = Utils.GetElementWorldScale(element);

    quat quat = new quat(new vec3(Utils.ToRadians(rotation.X), Utils.ToRadians(rotation.Y), Utils.ToRadians(rotation.Z)));
    mat4 rotMat = new mat4(quat);

    BulletSharp.Math.Matrix btTranslation = BulletSharp.Math.Matrix.Translation(location.X, location.Y, location.Z);
    BulletSharp.Math.Matrix btRotation = new BulletSharp.Math.Matrix(rotMat.ToArray());

    return btRotation * btTranslation;
}

